# @media Query Ordering issues

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have created several @media Queries to try and capture different displays. Im using chrome developer tool and whenever I switch the size of display it defaults to whatevere media query is lowest in the css. My original solution to this was putting the smallest down bellow, but now when i test it with my monitor it says 1440px is being used instead of 1920px. So i solved my issue when it comes to Mobile devices but have recreated it with monitors. How can I get around this issue?

2286BowmanRoad.com

CSS sample Bellow it is replicated from high to low and consist of

Bottom -> Top 360, 375, 450, 680, 780, 1054, 1366, 1440, 1680, 1920, 2560, 3840

```
 /* Start of Media only <1920 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) { 

    .fancyText { font-size: 2em; }
    .smallerHeadline { font-size: 1.3em; }
    .content {border-top:8px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  width: 100%; }    .footer { font-size: 0.8em; float: left; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 35px; letter-spacing: 1pt; }
    .headline { letter-spacing: 0pt; font-size: 1.5em; }
    .Wrap { max-width:1050px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; }
    .imageHeader { font-size: 1.5em; }

  }
 /* End of Media only <1920 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

 /* Start of Media only <1680 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1680) { 

    .fancyText { font-size: 2em; }
    .smallerHeadline { font-size: 1.3em; }
    .content {border-top:8px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  width: 100%; }    .footer { font-size: 0.8em; float: left; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 35px; letter-spacing: 1pt; }
    .headline { letter-spacing: 0pt; font-size: 2em; }
    .Wrap { max-width:1050px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; }
    .imageHeader { font-size: 1.5em; }

 }
 /* End of Media only <1680 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

 /* Start of Media only <1440 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1440px) { 

    .fancyText { font-size: 2em; }
    .smallerHeadline { font-size: 1.3em; }
    .content {border-top:8px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  width: 100%; }    .footer { font-size: 0.8em; float: left; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 35px; letter-spacing: 1pt; }
    .headline { letter-spacing: 0pt; font-size: 2em; }
    .Wrap { max-width:1050px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; }
    .imageHeader { font-size: 1.5em; }

  }
 /* End of Media only <1440 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve], otherwise as it stands this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic) and should be closed as such.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0):

You structured your media queries incorrectly. You can either group all of your css that corresponds to each view port or you can target media queries on individual classes. Here is a guideline to see an example of properly structuring and the sequence.

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops)
// No media query since the extra-large breakpoint has no upper bound on its width
```

Comment: My issue comes down to the order of precedence i think as it always wants the lowest possible max-width, so when i look using iphone SE if 360px is the last css it uses it and if 1920 is last it takes that. I cant figure out how to prevent them from just using the last as this site looks very different between a monitor and phone. I updated my question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, please give more details about your problem. It would be much more helpful if you were able to share the CSS code that is not working so we can work with you to resolve the issue.

My first instinct is that you're not using media queries correctly, here's a couple examples for you to look at:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 960px) {
  #wrapper { width: 70%; }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 960px) {
  #wrapper { width: 100%; }
}
```

The first media query will activate for any device where the screen width is bigger or equal to 960px and the second media query will activate when the screen width is smaller or equal to 960px.

If you can, please update your post with more details about specifically what is working and some example CSS so we can help you resolve your problem.

Comment: And if my device is 960px? Which one wins?

Comment: That's up to the cascading nature of CSS. In my example, the bottom one would win simply because it gets loaded afterwards and overwrites the previous media query.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to better understand what im doing, Now i have attempted the cascade and updated my question above as now my problem is reversed.

Comment: Is this currently pushed on your website? I've opened it up and changed the resolution to 1920x1080 in the developer tools and it works perfectly. One thing I would like to say is change "1680" to "1680px", that will fix at least on of your bugs.

Comment: Ye it is currently on the website, and now working for me so I'm thinking chrome may of played a trick on me and not updated.

Comment: Could have been a caching issue. If you experience something like this in the future, clear the cache in your browser and then refresh the page. Glad you got it working :)